# how to add the Jackson deserializer to a list of Protobuf object type in spring project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind, protobuf-java

I am building an Spring api service supports both https rest and grpc api. and I have defined this protobuf message:

```
message User {
    string name = 1
}
```

and in my http rest controller, I have a batch create method accepting a list of users as json string:

```
@PostMapping(path = "api/users:batchCreate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<BatchCreateUsersResponse> batchCreateAnswers(@RequestBody final List<User> request) {
    // some work to create users from input
}
```

the json input could be like:

```
[
    {"name": "Tom"},
    {"name": "Jerry"}
]
```

but now, there is some issue with Jackson to convert the json input to a list of `User` protobuf objects. it seems like there is no deserializer for this specific type (`List<User>`) according to the error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FieldDescriptor]
```

does anyone know how to add a customised deserializer to make it capable of doing the conversion correctly? thanks